# How to manage Android gmaps overlays order

Tags: android, google-maps, mapbox, tiles

My desired goal is to add a TileOverlay in mbtiles format and rendering some gemetric object (mainly lines and polygons) in KML format.

The problem is that the MapBox map covers my KML polygons and i don't know how to manage the rendering order.

Via code i tried to load on map firstly the mbtile and then the KML polygons, with no luck.

I attach the code for further considerations

```
        TileOverlayOptions opts = new TileOverlayOptions();
        MapBoxOfflineTileProvider provider = new MapBoxOfflineTileProvider("/path/to/file.mbtiles");
        opts.tileProvider(provider);
        mbTileOverlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(opts);

        KmlLayer layer = null;
        try {
            layer = new KmlLayer(mMap, R.raw.mypolygons, mContext);
            layer.addLayerToMap();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thanks for your help

Here is a [link](https://pastebin.com/X3tZ5rb5) to the KML used

Comment: Could you share an example KML?

Comment: link to kml provided, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polygons defined in your KML don't have the `drawOrder` property set (see [this change](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/commit/8fbe89300fa24d6c8ecb3509bc11a75aafa000f9)) so the `zIndex` is set to the default (0).

As you don't define a `zIndex` for your `MapBoxOfflineTileProvider` it's also defaulted to 0. Try defining your `TileOverlayOptions` like this:

```
TileOverlayOptions opts = new TileOverlayOptions();
opts.zIndex(-1);
```